# Getting 'found nil' exception after performing Segue through present modally

Tags: ios, swift, exception, segue, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have to view controllers, from first controller's menu item click, a segue is performed by 'Present Modally' Segue which will open the second viewController (acting as a menu) when i press Refresh button on the second VC, it is calling the method from the first VC To refresh its data and load it on tableView. the problem is it is call the method from second to first VC but is returning nil on this line.

```
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

i think it is because the first VC is not active properly as it is in the background ( the second VC's background is transparent so that i can see the first VC at the back ). i'm new to swift and i don't know how to deal with it.

EDIT: This is the refresh method

```
   func refresh() {  

   //   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  //  present(DayView_Controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

   // self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // it is dismissing the first view controller instead of second



    ////////
    Extensions.ShowAlert(self.pwait, sender: self) // here it causing the exception on viewDidLoad
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/d/yyyy"
    let finaldate = formatter.string(from:date)
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
    // all the services are being call and getting reloaded on tableview
  }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tableView.dataSource = self // exception here
  }
```

2nd EIDT: now i'm dismissing the 2nd VC on the refresh click and call the method from 1st VC on the completion, still getting the same error.

```
 @IBAction func Refresh_CLick(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        DayView_Controller().refresh()

    })
  //  DayView_Controller().refresh()

}
```

Comment: Could we see a little more code. Perhaps the segue would be helpful. Perhaps the entire refresh method where `self.tableView.dataSource is called.

Comment: The first View controller will be deallocated and nil once you move to another view controller. You can't refresh data of first VC from second VC. Instead of that you can pass data from second VC to first VC.

Comment: @RyanPoolos i have performed the segue through storyboard.

Comment: is this possible that i dismiss the second view controller on refresh click and call the refresh method after dismissing it? @RajeshkumarR will it work?

Comment: put some code for refresh click and segue .

Comment: @KKRocks Now check please.

Comment: @RyanPoolos Now Check.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you need to do something like this:

1) Create protocol:

```
protocol RefreshDelegate {
    func dataChanged(data: [Items])
}
```

2) In your second view controller add:

```
var delegate: RefreshDelegate ?

if let del = delegate {
     del.dataChanged(data: items) // your refreshed data
}
```

3) In your first view controller add extension:

```
extension FirstViewController: RefreshDelegate {
    func dataChanged(data: [Items]) {
         // update your tableView data -> then reload
    }
}
```

Something like this. You should understand main idea.

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you check my 2nd edit? i have tried another thing.

Comment: @ShahtajKhalid implement my suggestions from answer. Its like 5 minutes of coding. Try it

Answer (score 0):

Use Delegate to refresh data

```
protocol RefreshDelegate: class {
    func refreshData(data: Int)
}
```

In your first view controller add delegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, RefreshDelegate {
```

In your prepare for segue method set delegate

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "go" {
        let viewController:SecondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        viewController.refreshDelegate = self
    }

}

// Delegate
    func refreshData(data: Int) {
        tableData = data
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

In second view controller add variable for delegate

```
weak var refreshDelegate: RefreshDelegate?
```

Now call refresh delegate from second view controller

```
@IBAction func refreshTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        self.refreshDelegate?.refreshData(data: 10)
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried this! on refresh click it is not refreshing the data.

Comment: it will be helpful if you show your code i.e your refresh function.

Comment: it should work. I have tested this solution on my end and it is working.

Comment: you got solution or not?

Comment: I got the solution. but not through this method. actually i'm new to swift so i was trying to keep it simple. i have it done it by calling the refresh method inside the unwind segue.